# Comprimir ficheiros no Powershell 4

Tags: windows, powershell

Tenho o Windows com o Powershell 4 num server. Gostava de comprimir ficheiros, e para isso conheço o Compress-Archive do Powershell. Como é que o instalo? É preciso mexer no .NET Framework?

Em princípio instalava-o com Install-Module, mas este não está disponível nesta versão do Powershell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uma vez que não consegui instalar o Compress-Archive no PS4, resolvi a minha questão da utilizando o método `CopyHere`, da seguinte forma:

```
    $fileAge = 180

    [byte[]] $emptyZipBytes = @(80,75,5,6,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)

    $logFiles = Get-ChildItem C:\logs  | Where-Object  {$_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-$fileAge)}
    
    $logFilePaths = @()
    
    foreach($logFile in $logFiles) {
        $logFilePaths += $logFile.FullName
        }
    
    $zipFile = C:\Archive\logs.zip

    If (![io.file]::Exists($zipFile)) {
        [io.file]::WriteAllBytes($zipFile,$emptyZipBytes)
    }

    If ($logFilePaths.Count -gt 0) {
        foreach ($fPath in $logFilePaths) {
          (New-Object -Com Shell.Application).NameSpace($zipFile).CopyHere($fPath, 0x14)
          
          Get-Process powershell -ea 0 | Where-Object MainWindowTile -match "(\d{1-3} concluído)|(Comprimindo...)" | Wait-Process
        }

        Remove-Item $logFilePaths
    }
```